# Sum column values based on condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, foreach, date-range

I'm an intern and I've been struggling to find a solution since this monday...
I'm new to VBA and I don't clearly see how I can sum cells from a column based on some conditions..I tried multiple code but as soon as my codes didnt work I deleted them.

So what I'm trying to do is the following;

I've got a worksheet called `worksheets("Amounts")` in which I've got a data base.

What I've been struggling to do since this Monday :
Sum the amounts value in column Q ( "AMOUNT")  Only if rows of  COL A, col B, col C, col , col E, col F  have equivalent cells value.

Then, I'd like to sum in col Q the amounts based on the previous condition and put the total in one single row in the place of the rows that contain common values.
Right after I'd like to delete each rows that were matching to one another to display the agregated amount with the common values. Like the following example;

My data base;

| COL A | COL B | COL C | COL E | COL F | COL Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CODE | STATUE | ATTRIBUTE | Country | Capital | AMOUNT |
| **A1** | **OK** | **Z1** | **ENGLAND** | **LONDON** | 400 |
| C1 | NOK | R2 | SPAIN | MADRID | 50 |
| **A1** | **OK** | **Z1** | **ENGLAND** | **LONDON** | 300 |
| D1 | PENDING | X | CANADA | OTTAWA | 10 |

the Output expected;

| COL A | COL B | COL C | COL E | COL F | COL Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CODE | STATUE | ATTRIBUTE | Country | Capital | AMOUNT |
| **A1** | **OK** | **Z1** | **ENGLAND** | **LONDON** | 700 |
| C1 | NOK | R2 | SPAIN | MADRID | 50 |
| D1 | PENDING | X | CANADA | OTTAWA | 10 |

==> So here we have only 2 rows with common value on col A, B, C, E and F. I'd like to sum the amounts of these two rows and delete these two rows to make a single one with these common values like the up-above example.

Obviously for the other rows that dont match with other rows I'd like to let them as they were.

**the database in worksheets("Amount") can vary and can get more or less rows**, so I will need to automatize this process.

Here is my last saved code:

````
Option Explicit

Sub agreg()
Dim i As Long
Dim ran1 As Range

ran1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Values").Range("A" & Worksheets("Values").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
For Each i In ran1
   If Cells(i, 1) = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value Then
       cells(i,4) + range("D1",range("D1").End(xlDown)).Value
       
    End If
Next i

   
End Sub  ```
````

Comment: What about using Powerquery or Powerpivot instead. No need to use VBA and if why do 't you group the rows as needed.

Comment: Another comment: You do not mention what should happen with the columns G to P or what data they contain if any and what you want to do with them in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub SumUnique5Cols()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, arrQ, rngDel As Range, i As Long, dict As Object
   
   Set sh = Worksheets("Amounts")
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row based on A:A column
   arr = sh.Range("A2:Q" & lastRow).Value2               'place the range in an array to make the code faster
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")       'set a dictionary to keep the unique keys combination value
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)            'iterate between the array elements
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6)) Then 'if the combination key does not exist:
            dict.Add arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6), arr(i, 17)   'it is created (and take the value of Q:Q cell)
        Else                          'if the key aleready exists, it adds the value in the key item:
            dict(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6)) = dict(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6)) + arr(i, 17)
            'range of the rows to be deleted is filled in this way:
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = sh.Range("A" & i + 1)                 'if the range does not exist, it is set (i + 1, because of iteration starting from the second row)
            Else
                Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i + 1)) 'if it exists, a union between the previus range and the new one is created
            End If
        End If
   Next i
   If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete     'if there are rows to be deleted, they are deleted
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row     'recalculate the last row (after rows deletion)
   arr = sh.Range("A2:Q" & lastRow).Value2                   'place the remained range in an array
   ReDim arrQ(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)                      'ReDim the final array (to keep the summ) according to the remained rows
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arrQ(i, 1) = dict(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6)) 'put in the array the corresponind dictionary key value
   Next i
   sh.Range("Q2").Resize(UBound(arrQ), 1).value = arrQ       'drop the array content at once
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much FanDuru!
I tried it and it worked well! But what if columns aren't A,B,C,E,F and Q but D,E,F,N and Q instead?  I tried to adapt it but I got errors...

Comment: @Mido88 Very simple... You keep the same array, the same logic and **try understanding what the next line means**: `arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6))`. It means column 1(A) concatenated with 2(B), with 3(C), 5(E) and 6(F) on the array `i` row. You should use 4, 5, 6, 14 and 17... Should I adapt it? I can do it easily, but you will better learn doing by yourself, after understanding the code logic, I think... I tried commenting all the code lines. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

Comment: Hye FaneDuru. I understood what these lines mean. However when I tried  to change them into different column I got the following error message :" the indice doesn't belong to selection"

Comment: I changed every `arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6)`  with `arr(i, 4) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6) & arr(i, 14)`  it should be fine, isn't it ?

Comment: @Mido88 Did you do it when dropping the values from dictionary, too? On which line this error appear? Is it the line `arrQ(i, 1) = dict(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6))`? If this one, the (adapted) dictionary does not contain such a key...

Comment: @Mido88 I am afraid, what you tries is not so logic... I mean, if I correctly understood your question, in column "Q:Q" there are values which will not be the same. So the code will summarize only the one having the same value in "Q". Does your data keep the summ in another column? If yes, I suppose you adapted the dictionary item, too...

Comment: yes the error appear in this line you mentionned.
So `arrQ(i, 1) = dict(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6))` should be `arrQ(i, 4) = dict(arr(i, 4) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6) & arr(i, 14)` right ?

Comment: Yes there are different amount in column QQ that must be summ only if there are common values in every rows. The sum must only get in column Q with the previous condition.Could you tell me what I didn't understand please ? I dont know why I'm getting blocked to be honest

Comment: @Mido88 `arrQ(i, 1) = dict(arr(i, 4) & ...` Not `arrQ(i, 4)`. The final array has only a column and `arrQ(i, 4)` does not exist (column 4...). Please, read carefully all code line comments and ask if something is not clear. **Without understanding the code logic it is difficult to adapt it only be guessing**... I said that the code tries to create **unique keys** by concatenation of those columns, but if you introduce in the concatenation the column having the variable value, the result will not be the expecting one. It will summarize **only the keys also having the same value in "Q:Q"**...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235777/discussion-between-mido88-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query it would be simple:

- Group by those columns
- Aggregate by the `Sum` of `Amount`

Power Query is available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Change table name in next line to actual table name in the workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],

//set data types
//note the columns named ColumnN which will be different with your real data
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"CODE", type text}, 
        {"STATUE", type text}, 
        {"ATTRIBUTE", type text}, 
        {"Column1", type any}, 
        {"Country", type text}, 
        {"Capital", type text}, 
        {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type any}, {"Column5", type any}, {"Column6", type any}, {"Column7", type any}, {"Column8", type any}, {"Column9", type any}, {"Column10", type any}, {"Column11", type any}, 
        {"Amount", Int64.Type}}),

//group by columns 1,2,3,5,6
//return Sum of the Amount Column
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"CODE", "STATUE", "ATTRIBUTE", "Country", "Capital"}, 
        {{"Amount", each List.Sum([Amount]), type nullable number}})
        
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with VBA I would use ADODB to group the rows

```
Public Sub SumGroup()

    Dim connection As Object
    Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    Dim recordset As Object
        
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = "SELECT Code, Statue, Attribute, Country, Capital,  Sum(Amount) as SumAmount FROM [Database$] GROUP BY Code, Statue, Attribute, Country, Capital"
    
    Set recordset = connection.Execute(sSQL)
    Worksheets("Result").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset recordset
    
    recordset.Close
    connection.Close


End Sub
```

The data should be in a sheet with the name `Database`. The result will be written to a sheet with the name `Result`. Both sheets should exist in the workbook before running the code.

[image]
[image]

A Pivottable would give you what you want without any coding nor in VBA or M
[image]

Comment: strangely it doesn't work, I dont know wh

Comment: Sorry but I am afraid you have to be more specific. _Does not work_ is not really helpful to get at the issue.

Comment: I've got the following message :"Error execution, the data bose motor can't find "Database"$"

Comment: Did you name the worksheet which contains the data _Database_ like in my screenshot?

Comment: ohh nevermind I didnt see the picture on my laptoap , I had to check it on my phone. THank you very much, the code worked great. However I would like the final result to get displayed on the worksheets("Amount") the same as the starting sheet, what should I modify ? :/

Comment: The line `Worksheets("Result").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset recordset`  tells VBA where to put the result. So, you might want to try something like that `Worksheets("Amounts").Range("S1").CopyFromRecordset recordset`